# Macro Definition error for Macro : Closing parenthesis missing

Tags: gams-math

when I used the Macro facility had this error!
      **** Macro Definition error for Macro ISsame: Closing parenthesis missing
I checked all  parenthesis and it seems true, but I had same error again. Can you help me pleas?

```
set i/1*5/;
parameter 
a(i) /1 1,2 0,3 1,4 0,5 0/
b(i) /1 0,2 1,3 1,4 0,5 0/
c(i) /1 1,2 0,3 1,4 0,5 0/
d(i) /1 1,2 0,3 1,4 0,5 1/
e(i) /1 1,2 1,3 1,4 0,5 1/;

*check two parameter are equal or not
parameter same;

$ontext

same = sum(i, abs(a(i)-b(i)));
if(same > 0,
   display 'Parameter a is not equal to parameter b', same;);
$offtext   


* Define Macro
$macro ISsame(a(j),b(j))   same = sum(i, abs(a(i)-b(i))); if(same > 0,display 'Parameter a is not equal to parameter b', same;);


* End of Macro definition

* Call Macro                        
ISsame(a(j),b(j) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the argument list of `ISSame`. These arguments should be "pure identifiers", no parentheses are expected there, so you should change `$macro ISsame(a(j),b(j))` to `$macro ISsame(a,b)`. And also, whenn you call it, I guess you want to pass on `a` and `b` completely. So, overall you should have this:

```
...
* Define Macro
$macro ISsame(a,b)   same = sum(i, abs(a(i)-b(i))); if(same > 0,display 'Parameter a is not equal to parameter b', same;);


* End of Macro definition

* Call Macro                        
ISsame(a,b)
```